# Pivoting a table containing form replies in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a a dataframe containing replies from a form (20 questions -> 20 columns in the dataframe) that looks as follows :

```
Name | Q1         | Q2         | Q3         |  Q4        | ...

A    | Very well  | Quite well | Quite well |Not at all  | ...
B    | Fairly well| Little     | Very Little|Not at all  | ...
C    | Very well  | Quite well | Quite well |Fairly well | ...
 ....
```

Note that each proficiency level is not necessarily represented in each column.

I would like to pivot this table to get a table that looks as follows :

```
Proficiency| Q1         | Q2         | Q3         |  Q4        | ...

Very Little|NaN         | NaN        | B          | NaN        | ...      
Little     | NaN        | B          | ...
Well       | NaN        | 
Quite well | NaN        | A,C        | ...
Fairly well| B          | 
Very  well | A,C        | .......
 ....
```

Basically I would like to get a table that contains the name of the people clustered by question and proficiency level. I tried to use pandas pivot_table function but didn't manage to get what I needed.

I managed to create the table by iterating on the original dataframe and creating a new dataframe. However, I was wondering if there was a simplest way to do it using some pandas functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
print(
    df.melt("Name").pivot_table(
        index="value", columns="variable", values="Name", aggfunc=", ".join
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
variable       Q1    Q2    Q3    Q4
value                              
Fairly well     B   NaN   NaN     C
Little        NaN     B   NaN   NaN
Not at all    NaN   NaN   NaN  A, B
Quite well    NaN  A, C  A, C   NaN
Very Little   NaN   NaN     B   NaN
Very well    A, C   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

---

`df` used:

```
  Name           Q1          Q2           Q3           Q4
0    A    Very well  Quite well   Quite well   Not at all
1    B  Fairly well      Little  Very Little   Not at all
2    C    Very well  Quite well   Quite well  Fairly well
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Way more beautiful than my trusty dirty python loop. 
At first I was wondering why the solution wasn't working on my real df but it is just because instead of Names, I had IDs that were numerical values and not strings so the aggregating functions was not working properly. Just in case somehow faces the same issue.